# Gantt Chart Predecessors using JSGrid control

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, gantt-chart

I am trying to create a Gantt Chart generator, using the Share point control:

```
<Sharepoint:JsGrid>
```

I followed this tutorial: [How to: Create a Gantt Chart Using the JS Grid Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407962.aspx)

I also linked my Sharepoint TaskList as the data Source.

I developped a system of filters using some XML.

But I now want to manage predecessors and represent dependencies by an arrow.

To manage them, I used the last parameter of the EnableGantt function (`ganttDependentsColumnName`), which one just need the name of the column which contains the dependency information.

What I have to put in this column ?

What I tried is to fill it with the ID of the task, the lane of the DataRow containing predecessors, and I tried to put an object of the class Dependency :

```
class Dependency : IJsonSerializable
{
    public object Key {get; set;} // RecordKey
    public LinkType{get; set;} //LinkType

    public string ToJson(Serializer s)
    {
        return JsonUtility.SerializeToJsonFromProperties(s,this);
    }
}
```

(This code is from the answers in the tutorial)

In the Key, what do I have to put? If someone did it or know how to do it, It could be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still facing this issue. But this is what we did for the `Predecessors` column and this is as far as I understand this:

1] Change the Dependency class a bit to add a constructor as shown (otherwise it errors out).

2] Then, you basically need to pass a `Dependency` array to the `Predecessors` column which means that the JSGrid control needs to know the starting point/row and the ending point/row of the dependency (thus an array is required). JSON Serialization is taken care of already because of the inheritance and the `ToJson` methods so no worries there.

Code:

1] Dependency Class:

```
public class Dependency : IJsonSerializable
{
    public object Key { get; set; } // recordKey
    public LinkType Type { get; set; } // SP.JsGrid.LinkType

    public Dependency() {
        Key = DBNull.Value;
        Type = LinkType.FinishStart;
    }

    public string ToJson(Serializer s)
    {
        return JsonUtility.SerializeToJsonFromProperties(s, this);
    }
}
```

2] Add column if not targeting a SharePoint Task List (where data is an object of DataTable):

```
data.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Predecessors",typeof(Dependency[])));
```

3] Set the right object array to the `Predecessors` column:

```
    if (<<A predecessor exists>>){
    Dependency[] dep = new Dependency[2];
    dep[0] = new Dependency();
    try{
        /*
        // Unique Identifier for your row based on what you are 
        // passing to the GridSerializer while initializing it 
        // (as a third parameter which is called keyColumnName)
        // In my case I had to get it by doing some coding as  
        // shown. The first object in the array represents the 
        // previous row and so the unique identifier should  
        // point to the previous row
        */
        dep[0].Key = (
                data.Select(
                    "ID=" + 
                    data.Rows[s]["PredecessorsID"].ToString()
                    )
                    [0]["Key"]
                );
    }catch (Exception ex){ 
        dep[0].Key = DBNull.Value; 
    }
    dep[0].Type = LinkType.FinishStart;

    /*
    // Unique Identifier for your row based on what you are 
    // passing to the GridSerializer while initializing it 
    // (as a third parameter which is called keyColumnName)
    // In my case I had to get it by doing some coding as  
    // shown. The second object in the array represents the 
    // current row and so the unique identifier should  
    // point to the current row
    */
    dep[1] = new Dependency();
    try{ 
        dep[1].Key = data.Rows[s]["Key"]; 
    }catch (Exception ex){ 
        dep[0].Key = DBNull.Value; 
    }
    dep[1].Type = LinkType.StartFinish;
    data.Rows[s]["Predecessors"] = dep;
}
```

Finally, pass the `Predecessors` column while calling the `EnableGantt()` function:

```
gds.EnableGantt(
    Convert.ToDateTime(
        dr["start Date"]
    ), 
    Convert.ToDateTime(
        dr["Due Date"]
    ), 
    GanttUtilities.GetStyleInfo(), 
    "Predecessors"
    );
```

Make sure that your *StartFinish* and *FinishStart* link types **matches** the correct rows and that your tasks are listed correctly with correct task start dates and task end dates and predecessor keys.